# Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени от глаголов «решить» и «решать»

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, причастия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как образовать страдательные причастия прошедшего времени от глаголов *реш**и**ть* и *реш**а**ть*?

Answer (score 1):

Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются **от переходных глаголов совершенного вида.**

Поэтому причастие можно образовать только от глагола совершенного вида *решить*: 
***решить — реш/енн/ый.*** Другие примеры: ***купленный, брошенный, пойманный.***

При наличии приставки часто меняется вид глагола: нести (НВ) — принести (СВ) — принесенный.

От глагола несовершенного вида ***решать*** страдательное причастие прошедшего времени образовать нельзя.

Comment: Но ведь есть в словарях слово "читанный". Чего тогда исключать образование слова "решанный"?

Comment: У Зализняка в словаре нет такой формы в парадигме глагола решать: https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-paradigm-term-63171.htm

Answer (score -2):

Действительные причастия прошедшего времени:
Решить - **решивший**.
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/решивший](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9)
Решать - **решавший**.
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/решавший](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени:
Решить - **решённый**.
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/решённый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
Решать - **решанный**. || Слово почти нигде не используется, 120 результатов в Google.

Взаимоотношение страдательных и действительных причастий:
*Решённая человеком задача. Он её решил.*
*"Решанная" человеком задача. Он её решал, но так и не решил.*

Answer (score -3):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, как образовать страдательные причастия
>   прошедшего времени от глаголов РЕШИТЬ и РЕШАТЬ?

Вообще-то оба глагола страдательных причастий не образуют.

Бесприставочные глаголы совершенного вида вообще редко образуют причастия. Форма "решенный" крайне сомнительна, тут скорее можно говорить об отглагольном прилагательном.

Поэтому рекомендацией будет заменять на формы ***решившийся и решавшийся***, не имеющие ограничений в употреблении.

(+)
Глагол решить - вообще довольно своеобразный. Он многое сохранил с тех пор, когда считался глаголом несовершенного вида (современное - "решать").

У Пушкина:
...Ее сомнений
Мартын Задека не *решит*;
Но сон зловещий ей сулит
Печальных много приключений.

Явно используется как глагол несовершенного вида. Отсюда и многие сложности в понимании его парадигмы.

Comment: Что-то я не пойму Вашей трактовки. Вопрос решённый - прилагательное (закрытый); Пример, решённый Ваней вчера в классе - явно причастие, это же причастный оборот, а не прилагательное с зависимыми словами, здесь нет качественного признака, здесь действие в прош. времени - пример, который Ваня решил вчера в классе.

Comment: А когда глагол решить считался глаголом несов. вида? Где об этом написано. По-моему, его сложность только в этимологии:  Реши́ть. Общеслав. Того же корня, что латышск. ràisīt «развязывать», rist «завязывать», и др. Исходное значение — «вязать», далее — «завязывать» и «развязывать» (ср. конец — начало, см.), далее — «освободить» (в словенском яз. еще отмечается) и «решиться» — освободиться (от сомнений), прийти к какому-л. выводу. Ср. развязать себе руки

Comment: *А когда глагол решить считался глаголом несов. вида? Где об этом написано* - у Пушкина.

Comment: *явно причастие, это же причастный оборот* - вот не знаю... Сама фраза натянутая. да, здесь замена на "решившийся" тоже не очень, но это все, с чем я могу согласиться.

Comment: Решить: https://books.google.ru/books?id=7U7TAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA550&lpg=PA550&dq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83+%D1%83+%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=RxY519dHUZ&sig=ACfU3U0h35aJyMPGnKKFjtoKBHKBOYpP2Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMrtCr6PHkAhUHtosKHZ1IB24Q6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83%20%D1%83%20%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false

Comment: По-моему, там речь не о том, что решил - глагол несов. вида, а о том,что он был "до некоторой степени двувидовым". Пушкин употреблял его (в данном примере) в настоящем историческом. Сомнения Татьяны в Онегине должен  "решить" Задека, но он действие совершил(написал) когда-то, а разрешает её сомнения сейчас, по сути, это стилистический приём - употребление совершенного вида буд.вр.  в значении несовершенного наст.вр. . Дальше в этой статье говорится, что сам Пушкин "практически употреблял глагол решать во всех формах, которые отвергал теоретически".

Comment: @Людмила, я ту статью не собираюсь обсуждать так подробно. В контексте данного вопроса мне вполне достаточно вашей формулировки "до некоторой степени". Но если ставить вопрос ребром - посмотрите Карамзина, например, в Нацкорпусе.  Ни одного бесспорного употребления в качестве СВ - против огромного количества бесспорного НВ.

Comment: "Сия часть России и Москвы, сия тысячная дружина Иоаннова, сей новый двор, как отдельная собственность царя, находясь под его непосредственным ведомством, были названы опричниною, а все остальное ― то есть, все государство ― земщиною, которую Иоанн поручал боярам, земским, князьям Бельскому, Мстиславскому и другим, велев старым государственным чиновникам ― конюшему, дворецкому, казначеям, дьякам ― сидеть в их приказах, **решить** все дела гражданские, а в важнейших относиться к боярам, коим дозволялось в чрезвычайных случаях, особенно по ратным делам, ходить с докладом к государю.

Comment: Будучи подобно отцу ревнителем самодержавия, твердым, непреклонным, хотя и менее строгим, он следовал тем же правилам в политике внешней и внутренней; **решил** важные дела в совете бояр, учеников и сподвижников Иоанновых; их мнением утверждая собственное, являл скромность в действиях монархической власти, но умел повелевать; любил выгоды мира, не страшась войны и не упуская случая к приобретениям, важным для государственного могущества; менее славился воинским счастием, более опасною для врагов хитростию;

Comment: Есть ещё http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=0GENxiQeyWo%3D&tabid=10183 -Ильинская подтверждает Ваши слова:"... время Пушкина — это переломный момент в истории глагола решить, момент его включения в систему глаголов сов. вида и образования парного к нему глагола несов. вида решать". Там есть и о существовании страдат. причастий: "Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени также имеют значение совершенного вида, что, как известно, характеризует не только данный глагол, но и вообще глаголы несовершенного вида".