# грамматика: "Ее сомнений Мартын Задека не решит"

Tags: аспектология

Как вы понимаете выделенное предложение? Не выглядит странным в имеющемся контексте? Если нет, объясните, как понимать.

Иначе сделайте, пожалуйста, хотя бы частичный синтаксический разбор: интересует семантика и грамматика глагола в этой конструкции (модальность, наклонение, время, вид... - ну что там еще есть у глагола).

Ее тревожит сновиденье.
Не зная, как его понять,
Мечтанья страшного значенье
Татьяна хочет отыскать.
Татьяна в оглавленье кратком
Находит азбучным порядком
Слова: бор, буря, ведьма, ель,
Еж, мрак, мосток, медведь, метель
И прочая. ***Ее сомнений

Мартын Задека не решит;***
Но сон зловещий ей сулит
Печальных много приключений.
Дней несколько она потом
Все беспокоилась о том.

Пушкин, Е. О., 5:XXIV

Личность Мартина Задеки - предмет споров и толкований, но мне он сейчас не интересен.
По поводу ***"не решит"*** сразу скажу, что без дополнительных разъяснений фраза кажется странной, вырванной из контекста и в другой контекст засунутой.
Объяснений же слышал минимум два, одно из которых некоторое время считал исчерпывающим, но со временем энтузиазма поубавилось.

Плохи же эти объяснения тем, что при всей правдоподобности прямых доказательств не предполагают, поэтому я их пока и не предъявляю, жду независимых объяснений.

@Alex_ander

Уф... Вижу, меня не поняли. Я же просил, если вы считаете, что поняли Пушкина, дать синтаксический разбор. Ладно, разжую.

> А как насчет "не решит сомнений" = "подтвердит опасения"?

Пересказывать Пушкина своими словами - занятие неблагодарное. Смысловых синонимов можно подобрать много (*не разрешит проблем, не даст ответа на вопрос, не устранит роблему и проч.*), да только не о том вопрос мой. Сравните, у Пушкина (на первый взгляд по крайней мере) грамматическое будущее время. В какой семантической функции? Условное? Предполагаемое? Неизбежное?

При этом в контексте до этого места - все сплошь настоящее/прошедшее. И вы своё объяснение даете не в будущем времени, а в настоящем и в сослагательном наклонении. Другими словами, книга ***не решит*** проблему. Когда иили при каком условии? Ведь она уже посмотрела или смотрит в момент повествования. То есть логичнее было бы "не решает". Вот в чем непонятка-то.

Comment: А как насчет "не решит сомнений" = "подтвердит опасения"? Её беспокоило всё перечисленное, она хотела по соннику убедиться, что все это не так плохо (тогда она успокоилась бы и не сомневалась, что все хорошо), но эти слова и впрямь означают нечто неблагоприятное и при этом неясное. Вот тут люди конкретно по соннику разбирались со словами: https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5db879ae2fda8600b05ce505/devushka-i-medved-5df9f659bb892c00affe3d53

Comment: @Alex_ander - *А как насчет "не решит сомнений" = "подтвердит опасения"* - а что, простите, "как"? Вы смысл пересказываете, а меня грамматика интересует. В в тексте вопроса пояснение сделаю.

Comment: Грамматика в смысле почему "решит" вместо "разрешит"?

Comment: @Alex_ander  *почему "решит" вместо "разрешит"* - Ээээ... Уже интересно. Я, конечно, не это имел в виду... Разницы не вижу. Но развейте, пожалуйста, эту мысль. Какой, на ваше мнение, вид у этих двух глаголов?!

Comment: Совершенный вид, будущее время - в сочетании с настоящим временем действий персонажа. Значение невозможности желаемого результата, тщетности усилий, высказанное со стороны. Она пытается найти успокоение, но напрасно: результат пишущему ясен, предсказуем.

Comment: О! Вот с этого и надо было начинать. Итак, вы считаете нормальной (для Пушкина!) фразу построенную по принципу *"Я **читаю** книгу, книга меня не **удовлетворит**", "Я **иду** в банк за кредитом, банк мне кредита **не даст**"*?!  Речь о сочетаемости видо-временных форм глаголов, не более. Можете привести хоть один бесспорный пример подобной фразы из классики?

Comment: А здесь другое: **он** _идет_ в банк, но _не возьмёт_ он кредит - **я**-то знаю его кредитную историю.

Comment: Вот этого уже не понимаю. Почему другое? С точки зрения грамматики. === Ну и не поленюсь еще цитату дать. *Совершенное равенство прав; атаманы и старшины, избираемые народом, временные исполнители народных постановлений; круги, или совещания, где каждый казак имел свободный голос и где все общественные **дела решены** были большинством голосов; никаких письменных постановлений;* - (П. История Пугачевского бунта) здесь-то что у Пушкина?  Тоже совершенный вид?!

Comment: Ладно, если интересно, гляньте тут мой разговор с Людмилой. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456053 Там и ссылки есть. Извините, что сразу не раскрыл карты, мне хотелось, чтобы вы четко определились с позицией.

Comment: А точку с запятой не лучше убрать в конце цитирования?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - принято, спасибо.