# от какой формы глагола образуются страдательные причастия прошедшего времени

Tags: орфография, причастия

1. правило "[Н/НН в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_106)" на сайте gramota.ru

"...условия, при которых пишется две буквы Н":

> 2. причастие образовалось от глагола совершенного вида, например,
>    РЕШЕННАЯ ЗАДАЧА - от глагола РЕШИТЬ (что сделать? – соверш. вид);

НО почему утверждается, что причастие *решенная* произошло от *решить*, а не от *решать*?

2. вот [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/456063/184105) @Sharon говорит:

> Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от переходных глаголов совершенного вида.

Если есть возможность, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на источник, в котором говорится, что страдательные причастия прошедшего времени всегда образуются от переходного глагола совершенного вида.

Comment: *НО почему утверждается, что причастие решенная произошло от решить, а не от решать?* — потому что от "решать" будет "решанная" и потому что у "решать" несовершенная форма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> НО почему утверждается, что причастие решенная произошло от решить, а
> не от решать?

Это исторический факт. Все дело в том, что совсем недавно глагол "решить" был глаголом несовершенного вида, а глагола "решать" не существовало вовсе.

Испытывать колебания в видо-временной форме глагол "решить" начал только в XIX веке.

*Пруфы (если потребуются), дам позже, сейчас нет возможности*

Хотя вот у Пушкина

> У нас многие (между прочими и г. Каченовский, которого, кажется,
> нельзя упрекнуть в незнании русского языка) спрягают: решаю, решаешь,
> решаем, решаете, решают вместо решу, решишь и проч. Решу спрягается
> как грешу.

[ПСС](https://books.google.ru/books?id=INxrCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA310&lpg=PA310&dq=%D0%A3+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81+%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5+(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B8+%D0%B3.+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F+%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)+%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82:+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E,+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C,+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC,+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5,+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82+%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83,+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C+%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87.+%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83+%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83.&source=bl&ots=R1uqGIOBmE&sig=ACfU3U19WiGoyOJZzco6z9prCLegXLdAAA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVj6K-1N_1AhUmAhAIHeuJA3oQ6AF6BAgUEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%A3%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3.%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%3A%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87.%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83.&f=false)

> страдательные причастия прошедшего времени всегда образуются от
> переходного глагола совершенного вида.

Если вопрос о совершенном виде, то уже потому, что причастия, образованные от глаголов НСВ, имеют семантику настоящего времени и никакую другую. Это общее правило.

(+) ====

А что до всего остального...
Ну попробуйте вообще страдательное причастие образовать от глагола несовершенного вида. Получите максимум отглагольное прилагательное: ***читан(н)ый, хоженый, крашен(н)ый*** - эти формы не несут в себе семантики состояния, то есть отнесение их к прилагательным весьма логично.

Ну а что касается самого утверждения, что "всегда" от переходного глагола, то есть о чем поговорить.

Скажем так. Не всегда, но исключения крайне редки - и зачастую связаны с систематикой и терминологией. Например "руководимый" - по всем остальным признакам типичное причастие, но глагол "руководить" в классических моделях грамматики вообще не является переходным, поэтому приходится либо относить "руководимый" к прилагательным, либо пересматривать само определение переходности. По мне так второй путь перспективнее.

(++)===

Ну и "до кучи" - к вопросу о несовершенстве всей системы причастий.

Скажем, окказионализмы, имеющие семантику "причастий" будущего времени.

> Так вот что ожидает немцев, сейчас ***пойдущих*** в атаку, чтобы раздавить
> один-единственный несчастный эскадрон.

Гумилев, "Записки кавалериста".
(Курсив - мой, b-s)

Тут не страдательное причастие (страдательное тут невозможно даже в принципе, семантики такой нет), но очень характерный пример того, что некоторые, казалось бы востребованные языком, формы на самом деле не имеют нормативной реализации. Вот с причастиями прошедшего времени от глаголов НСВ примерно та же история.

Answer (score 2):

**О страдательных причастиях  прошедшего времени** https://studopedia.info/5-101587.html

Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от **переходных** глаголов **СВ и НСВ** (причастия от глаголов НСВ **немногочисленны**) от основы прошедшего времени с помощью суффиксов:

-н(н)- от глаголов на -ать, -ять и -еть: прочита-нн-ый,

-ен(н)- от основ на согласный и -ить: унес-енн-ый, построенный,

-т- от основ на -нуть, -оть, -ереть и от односложных глаголов и производных от них: замкну-т-ый, коло-т-ый, запер-т-ый, би-т-ый, разби-т-ый.

Обычно в учебниках, в том числе для вузов, образование таких причастий от глаголов **НСВ** не упоминается. С другой стороны,  наличие зависимого слова переводит отглагольное прилагательное **в причастие**: *крашеный – крашенный в прошлом году*.

Орфографический словарь: крашенный; кр. ф. -ен, -ена, **прич.**

Comment: Sharon По поводу материала по вашей ссылке, а где там обещанные примеры образований ***страдательных причастий прошедшего времени от глаголов НСВ***? Ну хотя бы один? ===== Да и вообще, этот материал сам по себе - предмет для обсуждения, мне кажется, там де-факто используется внутренне противоречивая систематика (одно утверждение, что некоторые причастия образуются от непереходных глаголов, рушит всю классическую схему, а авторы этого не "замечают"). Но обсуждать здесь и сейчас я не предлагаю, пусть хоть один пример по теме вопроса будет.

Comment: Меня это тоже как раз удивило. что примеров у них нет. Но я решила, что они их просто не приводят... надо где-то еще поискать. В то же время факт существования причастий при наличии зависимых слов тоже как-то  не вписывается в теорию.  Надо тогда считать это переходом из одной части речи в другую?  Посмотрела в вузовском учебнике: о переходе тоже ничего не сказано.

Comment: А вот насчет взаимоперехода причастий-прилагательных - я этот разговор помню с 80-х годов прошлого века. Аванесов именно так и трактовал, даже больше - де-факто признавал отглагольные прилагательные и страдательные причастия единой частью речи, поскольку грамматическая разница определяется лишь контекстно (орфография - не в счет, она условна).  Я давно не слежу, но вопрос, как понимаю, не решен, все-таки это сильное потрясение для классических моделей грамматики.

Comment: Да, вы правы, как-то этот вопрос обходят стороной. Хотела в корпусной грамматике почитать статью о страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени. А там все причастия расписаны, кроме этой группы.

Answer (score 1):

1. ‟Решать” — несовершенный глагол, а от несовершенных глаголов нельзя образовать совершенное причастие, как в сочетании ‟решенная задача”. ‟Решить” — совершенный глагол, от него можно образовать совершенное причастие; от него и образовано причастие ‟решённая”.
2. Причастия страдательного залога прошедшего времени все совершенные, а поэтому образуются от совершенных. Не существует страдательных несовершенных причастий прошедшего времени.  Например, от несовершенного глагола ‟избивать” нельзя образовать страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, но можно от совершенного глагола ‟избить” — ‟избитый человек”.
   Что касается переходности, то если глагол непереходный, то у него нет страдательного залога.